# Cell value equals all values of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with different values (some unique, some not), and i want to put only the unique ones in a cell value, each one separated by a "/".
So i filtered the list to a new range using AdvancedFilter with unique=true, but now i need a macro that takes all the values from this range and puts them in that cell.

How should i do that?

Thanks

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/: show us what you've tried if you want help. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've done this to filter :    Sheets("Facture").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Facture").Range("BB2"), Unique:=True

Comment: You can edit your post. I suggest you put your code there, in a code block (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)).

Comment: And then i wanted to use : For Each Cell In Rng, If Cell <> "" Then Assign Variable to Cell.Value, but i dont know how to assign as much variables as there are non blank cells found...

Answer (score 0):

I take it the filtered data with unique values is in sheet `Facture`, cell `BB2` and below. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```vb
Function foo() As String
  Dim oCell
  Dim s As String

  With Sheets("Facture")
    For Each oCell In .Range(.Range("BB2"), .Range("BB2").End(xlDown))
      s = s & "/" & oCell.value
    Next oCell
  End With
  
  foo = Mid(s, 2) 'To remove the initial "/"
End Sub
```

Comment: The preprocessed data is in sheet Facture cell A2 and below, in cell BB2 is the filtered list with only unique values

Comment: That's what I meant by "preprocessed". I apologize for the confusion. Answer edited!

Comment: Merçi beaucoup ;)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it worked for you so that other users don't try to uselessly help you. See [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).